# Unable to transfer app between two Apple Developer accounts

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm struggling with getting the new app transfer feature to work between two accounts I own. I'm transferring from an individual developer account onto an organization account, both under the regular (non-enterprise) iOS developer program.

When I pick an app on the source account and specify the destination Team Agent Apple ID and Team ID, I get the following error message:

```
The recipient's Team ID does not match the Team ID associated with the Apple ID of the recipient's Team Agent.
```

Considering that I've only used one single email on the destination, and that there seems to be only one Team ID I can locate, I don't quite get what I could be doing wrong. I'm wondering if there's a bug on their end somewhere and if anyone else has encountered it before.

Comment: Maybe you should ask apple developer support?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error is self explanatory. Their Team ID is not associated with the Team Agent. Double check your provisioning profiles and make sure everything matches. But I agree, this is not a good question for SO since it deals purely with Apple's process and not a language.

Comment: @DCGoD, There are no provisioning profiles on the destination account because provisioning profiles require there to be an AppID. The app ID exists only on the source side of the transfer, not on the destination side, which is empty, and will be empty until the transfer is completed.

As I mentioned in the question, I checked that on the destination account, the AppleID of the Team Agent and the team ID are correct.

Comment: @AlexWayne I am right now, but was hoping for a quicker resolution in case folks had run into this issue before.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an App Store and is not directly programming related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The support folks had to go in manually and fix things apparently, everything worked fine afterwards.

Contact them at itunesconnect@apple.com with the inquiry, include a screenshot of this issue in the email since they'll ask you for one anway.

Answer (score 4):

Recipient's Team Agent Apple ID (Apple Developer's account email) : User with the Developer Program Team Agent role. The Team Agent is authorized to enter into transfer agreements on behalf of the recipient company or organization.

Team ID: The unique identifier for the recipient's company or organization. Recipients can find the information in the Your Account pane of Organization Profile accessible from the Developer Member Center on developer.apple.com.